# process specifics line from text file

Tags: batch-file

i want to insert to text file like this: (the content of the text file is not like this, this is only example):

```
This Is The 1 line
This Is The 2 line
This Is The 3 line
This Is The 4 line
This Is The 5 line
This Is The 6 line
This Is The 7 line
This Is The 8 line
This Is The 9 line
This Is The 10 line
This Is The 11 line
This Is The 12 line
This Is The 13 line
This Is The 14 line
```

the new file will be like this:

```
This Is The 1 line
This Is The 2 line
This Is The 3 line
This Is The 4 line
This Is The 5 line
This Is The 6 line
This Is The 7 line
This Is The 8 line
This Is The 9 line
This Is The 10 line
NEW INPUT HERE
This Is The 11 line
This Is The 12 line
This Is The 13 line
This Is The 14 line
```

my question is how to process line 1-10, insert some text, and afterwords process line 11-14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one robust way to do it:

This uses a helper batch file called `findrepl.bat` (by aacini) - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfdldmcb6vwi9xc/findrepl.bat

Place `findrepl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or on the path.

```
@echo off
(
type "file.txt"|findrepl /o:1:10 
echo NEW INPUT HERE
type "file.txt"|findrepl /o:11
) > "newfile.txt"
```

Comment: A user named aacini wrote it, and repl.bat by dbenham is equally robust and useful.